# Getting Two Linux VMs to Ping Each Other

Tags: networking, redhat, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am using VMWare Workstation 14.1.8 with two Linux VMs: Red Hat 6 and Red Hat 7. I need them to be able to ping each other across the host machine which is Windows 10. I have them both set up using a custom specific virtual network (VMNet2 (Host Only) in the 192.168.116 range) and the IPs are:

RH6: 192.168.116.128

RH7: 192.168.116.129

For some reason, RH7 can ping RH6 but RH6 cannot ping RH7. I feel like my VMWare settings are correct and the problem lies in the RH6 network configuration. What steps can I take on the RH6 machine to fix the network configuration so that it pings the RH7 VM?

[This is what happens when I ping from RH7 to RH6 (success)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZrwq.png)

[And this is what happens when I try to ping from RH6 to RH7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc8sn.png)

**Edit:** Adding tcpdump output from RH6. So it seems that RH6 is somehow seeing RH7 because 00:0c:29:51:10:97 is the MAC address of the RH7 VM.

```
[root@cody-rh6 network-scripts]# tcpdump -ennqti eth0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.60172 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.60171 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.60171 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.60172 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.60171 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.60172 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, IPv4, length 92: 192.168.116.1.137 > 192.168.116.255.137: UDP, length 50
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, IPv4, length 92: 192.168.116.1.137 > 192.168.116.255.137: UDP, length 50
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.60171 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.60172 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, IPv4, length 92: 192.168.116.1.137 > 192.168.116.255.137: UDP, length 50
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.60171 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.60172 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.60171 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.60172 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.60171 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.60172 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 216: 192.168.116.1.49299 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 174
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 216: 192.168.116.1.49299 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 174
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 216: 192.168.116.1.49299 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 174
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 216: 192.168.116.1.49299 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 174
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.57946 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.57945 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.57945 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.57946 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.57945 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.57946 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, IPv4, length 92: 192.168.116.1.137 > 192.168.116.255.137: UDP, length 50
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.57945 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.57946 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, IPv4, length 92: 192.168.116.1.137 > 192.168.116.255.137: UDP, length 50
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.57945 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.57946 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, IPv4, length 92: 192.168.116.1.137 > 192.168.116.255.137: UDP, length 50
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.57945 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.57946 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.57945 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.57946 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ARP, length 42: Request who-has 192.168.116.129 tell 192.168.116.128, length 28
00:0c:29:51:10:97 > 00:0c:29:e9:65:f3, ARP, length 60: Reply 192.168.116.129 is-at 00:0c:29:51:10:97, length 46

WHERE I STARTED THE PING

00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 59971, seq 1, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 59971, seq 2, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 59971, seq 3, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 59971, seq 4, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 59971, seq 5, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 59971, seq 6, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 59971, seq 7, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 59971, seq 8, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 59971, seq 9, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 59971, seq 10, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 59971, seq 11, length 64
00:0c:29:51:10:97 > 01:00:5e:00:00:fb, IPv4, length 160: 192.168.116.129.5353 > 224.0.0.251.5353: UDP, length 118
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 59971, seq 12, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 59971, seq 13, length 64

ENDED PING

00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:ff:82:3b, IPv4, length 342: 192.168.116.128.68 > 192.168.116.254.67: UDP, length 300
00:50:56:ff:82:3b > 00:0c:29:e9:65:f3, IPv4, length 342: 192.168.116.254.67 > 192.168.116.128.68: UDP, length 300
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:c0:00:02, IPv4, length 79: 192.168.116.128.55467 > 192.168.116.1.53: UDP, length 37
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:ff:82:3b, ARP, length 42: Request who-has 192.168.116.254 tell 192.168.116.128, length 28
00:50:56:ff:82:3b > 00:0c:29:e9:65:f3, ARP, length 60: Reply 192.168.116.254 is-at 00:50:56:ff:82:3b, length 46
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:c0:00:02, ARP, length 42: Request who-has 192.168.116.1 tell 192.168.116.128, length 28
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 00:0c:29:e9:65:f3, ARP, length 60: Reply 192.168.116.1 is-at 00:50:56:c0:00:02, length 46
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:c0:00:02, IPv4, length 79: 192.168.116.128.55467 > 192.168.116.1.53: UDP, length 37
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:c0:00:02, IPv4, length 91: 192.168.116.128.40800 > 192.168.116.1.53: UDP, length 49
00:0c:29:51:10:97 > 00:50:56:ff:82:3b, IPv4, length 342: 192.168.116.129.68 > 192.168.116.254.67: UDP, length 300
00:50:56:ff:82:3b > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 342: 192.168.116.254.67 > 192.168.116.129.68: UDP, length 300
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 216: 192.168.116.1.49346 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 174
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 216: 192.168.116.1.49346 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 174
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:c0:00:02, IPv4, length 91: 192.168.116.128.40800 > 192.168.116.1.53: UDP, length 49
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 216: 192.168.116.1.49346 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 174
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.49349 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.49348 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.49348 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.49349 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.49348 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 216: 192.168.116.1.49346 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 174
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, IPv4, length 92: 192.168.116.1.137 > 192.168.116.255.137: UDP, length 50
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.49349 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.49348 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, IPv4, length 92: 192.168.116.1.137 > 192.168.116.255.137: UDP, length 50
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.49349 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.49348 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:0c:29:51:10:97 > 00:50:56:ff:82:3b, ARP, length 60: Request who-has 192.168.116.254 tell 192.168.116.129, length 46
00:50:56:ff:82:3b > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, ARP, length 60: Reply 192.168.116.254 is-at 00:50:56:ff:82:3b, length 46
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, IPv4, length 92: 192.168.116.1.137 > 192.168.116.255.137: UDP, length 50
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.49349 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.49348 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:c0:00:02, IPv4, length 81: 192.168.116.128.35443 > 192.168.116.1.53: UDP, length 39
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.49349 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.49348 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.49349 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:c0:00:02, IPv4, length 81: 192.168.116.128.35443 > 192.168.116.1.53: UDP, length 39
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:c0:00:02, IPv4, length 93: 192.168.116.128.56316 > 192.168.116.1.53: UDP, length 51
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:c0:00:02, IPv4, length 93: 192.168.116.128.56316 > 192.168.116.1.53: UDP, length 51
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:c0:00:02, IPv4, length 83: 192.168.116.128.52652 > 192.168.116.1.53: UDP, length 41
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:c0:00:02, ARP, length 42: Request who-has 192.168.116.1 tell 192.168.116.128, length 28
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 00:0c:29:e9:65:f3, ARP, length 60: Reply 192.168.116.1 is-at 00:50:56:c0:00:02, length 46
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:c0:00:02, IPv4, length 83: 192.168.116.128.52652 > 192.168.116.1.53: UDP, length 41
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:c0:00:02, IPv4, length 83: 192.168.116.128.52898 > 192.168.116.1.53: UDP, length 41
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:50:56:c0:00:02, IPv4, length 83: 192.168.116.128.52898 > 192.168.116.1.53: UDP, length 41
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.52566 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.52565 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.52566 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.52565 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.52566 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.52565 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, IPv4, length 92: 192.168.116.1.137 > 192.168.116.255.137: UDP, length 50
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.52566 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.52565 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, IPv4, length 92: 192.168.116.1.137 > 192.168.116.255.137: UDP, length 50
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.52566 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, IPv4, length 92: 192.168.116.1.137 > 192.168.116.255.137: UDP, length 50
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.52565 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.52566 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.52565 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 33:33:00:00:00:0c, IPv6, length 718: fe80::456e:a615:2dbc:c4bf.52566 > ff02::c.3702: UDP, length 656
00:50:56:c0:00:02 > 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa, IPv4, length 698: 192.168.116.1.52565 > 239.255.255.250.3702: UDP, length 656
```

Routing table from RH6:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.116.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Virtual Network Editor Settings:

[image: Virtual Network Editor Settings]

vmnet2 DHCP Settings (what both vm's are set to use):

[image: VMNet2 DHCP Settings]

So I was going to post the RH7 routing table as well earlier but it looks exactly the same as RH6:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.116.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens37
```

Here is what RH7 tcpdump looks like when I ping it from RH6:

```
[root@localhost groberts]# tcpdump -ennqti ens37
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens37, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 36126, seq 1, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 36126, seq 2, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 36126, seq 3, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 36126, seq 4, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 36126, seq 5, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, ARP, length 60: Request who-has 192.168.116.129 tell 192.168.116.128, length 46
00:0c:29:51:10:97 > 00:0c:29:e9:65:f3, ARP, length 42: Reply 192.168.116.129 is-at 00:0c:29:51:10:97, length 28
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 36126, seq 6, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 36126, seq 7, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 36126, seq 8, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 36126, seq 9, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 36126, seq 10, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 36126, seq 11, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 36126, seq 12, length 64
00:0c:29:e9:65:f3 > 00:0c:29:51:10:97, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.116.128 > 192.168.116.129: ICMP echo request, id 36126, seq 13, length 64
```

Final Edit: So it seems the firewall was the culprit. I ran "service firewalld stop" and RH6 receives pings from RH7 now:
[image]

Comment: tcpdump output would help. Try: "tcpdump -ennqti eth0 \( arp or icmp \)" You can also do "arping 192.168.116.129 -c 2" At a wild guess maybe you have another device on the bridge you are not aware of that has the same IP as RH6. In such a case you may not see the reply depending on the arp cache. You could quickly clear the arp cache on RH7 "arp -d 192.168.116.128" and then do a ping from RH6 and you might get lucky. But carefully check "arp -n" and make sure the MAC addresses from ifconfig <i/f> match.

Comment: I added a tcpdump from RH6 with a comment that it is trying to send a packet to RH7 because the RH7 MAC address is in the log.

Comment: Interesting, so it is getting the pings. Have you tried; echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all

Comment: or: sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=0

Comment: if that doesn't work, look at the routing table on both ends - the return path route would likely be wrong e.g. netstat -rn / route -n

Comment: "echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all" puts a 0 in icmp_echo_ignore_all

Comment: I added the routing table from RH6.

Comment: what's the table like on RH7? if RH7 cannot send the reply, or it is routed elsewhere then RH6 will not see the ping reply. Can you add the tcpdump for the RH7 end and do the ping again? then we can correlate the ICMP leaving 6, entering 7 and then see what MAC addr/IP RH7 is using to respond. You also did the icmp_echo_ignore_all  on he RH7 end right? Writing a 0 into a file in /proc/ is a way to send configuration settings to the kernel. In this case to make sure it is not filtering ICMPs. You should have 0 on both ends. I suspect a duplicate IP for RH6 on your network that RH7 sees

Comment: I added the routing table for RH7 and a sample of tcpdump when RH6 is pinging it. I did add a 0 into the file in /proc/. I don't have any other VMs assigned to vmnet02. Would it have to be a VM on vmnet02 to conflict?

Comment: Very odd, ok so at least this rules out another machine with the same IP. Your box truly does get the ping but does not respond. Is this SE linux or firewall enabled? If so some of the suggestions here might help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44596/what-prevents-a-machine-from-responding-to-pings

Comment: another option to try "sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2" https://access.redhat.com/solutions/53031 also mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536796/icmp-request-received-but-doesnt-reply

Comment: if it is reverse path filtering then "nstat -rsz | grep IPReversePathFilter" or "netstat -s | grep IPReversePathFilter" will show increasing drop counters - you might want to look at all the counters, send the output to a file, do a few pings and then diff the output of nstat/netstat with the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the firewall was the culprit. I ran "service firewalld stop" and RH6 receives pings from RH7 now.

Comment: thanks for updating - I hope the debugging steps helped a bit.

Comment: They helped a ton. I'm still learning the in's and out's of linux so learning any debugging steps like this is a huge help.